# Tikzpicture problem: Specifically for the "\Vertex" family, how do I position below or above the node

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: problem relates to the t=0, t=1, and t=2]

In the diagram, I want to move the t=0 below (or above) the node without adjusting to `\draw`, `\path` or `\node` code. Can I append some little piece of code such as `label=above{...}`, `anchor=south`, or something else somewhere in my code? It seems I need to adjust `\Vertex...`, but I don't know where to append anything to change the node's label.

My present code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{trees, fit,shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
  %banks path
.\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3] 

...\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]   

...\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->,font=\scriptsize}}=[circle,draw]   

......\Vertex[x=0,y=1.5]{t=0}   

......\Vertex[x=1,y=1.5]{t=1}   

......\Vertex[x=2,y=1.5]{t=2}   

......\Edges\[label = $1+r$\]\(t=0,t=1\)

......\Edges\[label = $1+r$\]\(t=1,t=2\)

.\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

I've spent over 3 hours constructing my diagram to look exactly as I want it to, and this is my final problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code complete with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not certain which of the packages are relevant at this point. I've gone through a few different versions of codes to make my tree and haven't really adjusted which packages are the ones in use, but the ones I put are the ones I have needed up until this point.

Comment: You're welcome! Add also your `documentclass` and I think it's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
 \usepackage[left=1cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{tkz-berge}
 \usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,arrows}
 \begin{document}
 %(tri) stock's path
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
    \SetUpVertex[Lpos=-90]
      \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=circle, fill=black,
                           minimum size=13pt,inner sep=0pt}
         }
        \Vertex[x=0,y=1.5]{S$_0$}
        \Vertex[x=1,y=2]{uS$_0$}
        \Vertex[x=1,y=1]{d$S_0$}
        \Vertex[x=2,y=1.5]{ud$S_0$}
        \Vertex[x=2,y=2.5]{u$^2$S$_0$}
        \Vertex[x=2,y=.5]{d$^2S_0$}
        \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->,font=\scriptsize},{below=15pt}}
            \Edge[label = $\widetilde{p}$](S$_0$)(uS$_0$) 
            \Edges[label = $1-\widetilde{p}$](S$_0$,d$S_0$)
            \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}$](uS$_0$,u$^2$S$_0$)
            \Edges[label = $1-\widetilde{p}$](uS$_0$,ud$S_0$)
            \Edges[label = $1-\widetilde{p}$](d$S_0$,d$^2S_0$)
            \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}$](d$S_0$,ud$S_0$)
 \end{tikzpicture}    
  \\
 %banks path
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
    \SetUpVertex[Lpos=-90]
     \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=circle, fill=black,
                           minimum size=13pt,inner sep=0pt}
         }
        \Vertex[x=0,y=1.5,]{t=0}
        \Vertex[x=1,y=1.5]{t=1}
        \Vertex[x=2,y=1.5]{t=2}
           \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->,font=\scriptsize,above,sloped,midway}}
              \Edges[label = $1+r$](t=0,t=1)
              \Edges[label = $1+r$](t=1,t=2)

   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

I have modified the code here

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
 \usepackage[left=1cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{tkz-berge}
 \usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,arrows}
 \begin{document}
 %(tri) stock's path
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
    \SetUpVertex[Lpos=-90]
      \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=circle, fill=black,
                           minimum size=13pt,inner sep=0pt}
         }
        \Vertex[x=0,y=1.5]{S$_0$}
        \Vertex[x=1,y=2]{uS$_0$}
        \Vertex[x=1,y=1]{d$S_0$}
        \Vertex[x=2,y=1.5]{ud$S_0$}
        \Vertex[x=2,y=2.5]{u$^2$S$_0$}
        \Vertex[x=2,y=.5]{d$^2S_0$}

        %\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->,font=\scriptsize,below=15pt}}
         \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->,font=\scriptsize,above,sloped,midway}}
            \Edge[label = $\widetilde{p}$](S$_0$)(uS$_0$) 
            \Edges[label = $1-\widetilde{p}$](S$_0$,d$S_0$)
            \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}$](uS$_0$,u$^2$S$_0$)
            \Edges[label = $1-\widetilde{p}$](uS$_0$,ud$S_0$)
            \Edges[label = $1-\widetilde{p}$](d$S_0$,d$^2S_0$)
            \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}$](d$S_0$,ud$S_0$)
 \end{tikzpicture}    
  \\
 %banks path
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
    \SetUpVertex[Lpos=-90]
     \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=circle, fill=black,
                           minimum size=13pt,inner sep=0pt}
         }
        \Vertex[x=0,y=1.5,]{t=0}
        \Vertex[x=1,y=1.5]{t=1}
        \Vertex[x=2,y=1.5]{t=2}
           \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->,font=\scriptsize,above,sloped,midway}}
              \Edges[label = $1+r$](t=0,t=1)
              \Edges[label = $1+r$](t=1,t=2)

   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I just figured away around my problem!! `%banks path
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
 \SetVertexNormal[LineWidth=3pt]
 \Vertex[x=0,y=1.5]{t=0}
   \Vertex[x=1,y=1.5]{t=1}
   \Vertex[x=2,y=1.5]{t=2}
                  \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->,font=\scriptsize}}=[circle,draw]
                  \Edges[style=above, label = $1+r$](t=0,t=1)
                  \Edges[style=above, label = $1+r$](t=1,t=2)
 \end{tikzpicture}`

However, your solution is much nicer so I'm going to use it! thank you so much! How can I decrease the size of the node?

Comment: `minimum size= ` @ThomasDevine

Comment: The code you have posted is not runable and gives me error, however i try my level best to get run and output.@ThomasDevine

Comment: Thank you so much! It works and it looks good! Hopefully my paper gets published at the end of all this, I'll come back and tell you that the beautiful code you gave me is out there being admired (critiqued?) lol

Comment: If this is the answer then please try to accept my answer by clicking on tickmark sign@ThomasDevine

Comment: I accepted it Biki! Thanks for the answer, sorry it took me so long, not familiar with accepting the solutions. :)